# Erro: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou setando uma série de "`checkboxes`" numa variável `lista`. Depois percorro a variável num laço para que apenas algumas delas sejam clicadas. Porém quando a checkbox não está visível na tela, o Selenium não clica e apresenta o erro. Se dou scroll até o checkbox aparecer, consigo clicar (sem usar o laço, enviando o comando `checkbox[n].click()` um a um). Quando consulto se o elemento "`is_displayed`", retorna `True`.

Meu código (que estava funcionando semana passada!) é:

```
def DistribuiProcesso():
    distribuir = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('selProNov771230778800100040000000000014')) 
    procuradores = distribuir.options
    for x in range(len(procuradores)):
        for y in range(len(processosAlvo)):
                if processosAlvo[y][2] in procuradores[x].text: #É onde está a informação que define se será ou não selecionado o checkbox!
                    processosAlvo[y][1].click() #É onde está o elemento checkbox.
        executar = browser.find_element_by_id('btnExecutar') #Localizo o botão de executar a tarefa.
        executar.click() #Clico no botão.
        voltar = browser.find_element_by_id('btnVoltar')
        voltar.click()
```

Minha dúvida: Alguma maneira de "rolar" a tela? `Keys.DOWN` e `time.sleep()` não ajudaram... ou então fixar o clique de alguma forma? Antes funcionava até com a janela minimizada!

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução colocando uma linha assim:

```
processosAlvo[y][1].send_keys('\ue007')
```

Ele seta com "Enter" antes, e aí clica.